# Changing Windows 10 Taskbar Preview Name and Icon

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons

I want to change the taskbar preview for an application to show a different name and a different icon for the app.

A while back, I was able to just make a shortcut for the application and just rename it as well as change the icon for it. When that shortcut was pinned to the taskbar, if you hovered over the icon- it displayed the new name. Even when the application was in use, if you hovered over the icon- the preview showed the new name, BUT the icon in the top-left of the preview was the original icon for the application.

I tried the same method today, but now the ORIGINAL icon AND name of the application show in the taskbar preview when the app is in use.

Is there a way to change this? I want the new icon and new name to show for the application in the thumbnail  taskbar preview.